# How would I use LINQ to XML to get the value from example XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Here is the xml I am trying to access:

```
<resourceStrings>    
    <globalStrings>
          <string>
             <key>RptTitle1</key>
             <value>Title1</value>
           </string>    
           <string>
              <key>RptTitle2</key>
              <value>ReportTitle2</value>
           </string>
            <string>
                <key>RptTitle3</key>
                <value>ReportTitle3</value>
            </string>
       </globalStrings>
</resourceStrings>
```

How would I use linq to xml to search for key of RptTitle1 and return the value of the value node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);

var setting = doc.Descendants("string").First(e => e.Element("key").Value == "RptTitle1");
var RptTitle1 = setting.Element("value").Value;
```

This code will find the first `<string>` element that has a `<key>` element with a value equal to `RptTitle1`, then get that element's `<value>` element.

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file.  If you still get an error, add a reference to System.Core.dll to your project.

Comment: got it, no errors. I thought all I needed was System.Xml.Linq.

Comment: @TampaRich: System.Xml.Linq is needed for the `XDocument`, `XElement`, etc classes. System.Core and System.Linq are needed for the generic Linq-to-Objects methods (like `First`).